# How do I determine a 'child' type from a parent's data type?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm not sure if my title really describes what I'm after, so I'll just show a piece of code first:

```
data IntegralExpression= Value Integer
       | Add IntegralExpression IntegralExpression
         deriving Show

data BooleanExpression = BValue Bool
       | And BooleanExpression BooleanExpression 
       | Or BooleanExpression BooleanExpression 
         deriving Show

data ParentExpression = BooleanExpression 
      | IntegralExpression
        deriving Show
```

The way I set this up, it makes sense to me that a ParentExpression can either be an IntegerExpression or BooleanExpression. However, I'm trying to accomplish a function that has a ParentExpression as input, which could (for example) be 'Value 5' (from the IntegerExpression child class). But upon compiling, it will say that it expects a ParentExpression and not an IntegerExpression. How can I create 1 general 'parent' that evaluates any child?

My function (for simplicity sake) looks something like this:

```
testConvert :: ParentExpression -> Integer
testConvert (Value n) = n
```

In my mind, this function should 'understand' that this concerns an IntegralExpression given that I call:

```
testConvert (Value 5)
```

However, it won't compile since Haskell expects something of type 'ParentExpression' whereas I input 'IntegralExpression'.

**So my question is:** How can I create a function with a parent datatype as its type, that accepts any form of input of its childs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
data ParentExpression = BooleanExpression | IntegralExpression
```

does not do what you probably think it's doing. What it does, is declaring a new datatype with two nullary constructors, that have nothing in common with the similarly named  datatypes  declared earlier.

In creating new datatypes, you need always to specify a constructor name, like

```
data ParentExpression = BExpr BooleanExpression | IExpr IntegralExpression
```

In Haskell, all values are explicitly "tagged" with their datatype constructors, e.g.:

```
testConvert :: ParentExpression -> Integer
testConvert (IExpr (Value n)) = n
```

there's no implicit type conversions in Haskell.

Comment: Ah I did not realize this! I am still fairly new to Haskell, but this explains everything. Thank you so much!